# How can I play video from URL in Codename One?

Tags: java, android, ios, cross-platform, codenameone

I am new in codename one
I couldn't find anything in the documentation of codename one about how to play video from URL in Codename one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(url, true);` to create a video object with a URL just like you can with a file. Notice that mobile platforms require HTTPS urls by default.